# If $A$ is an integral domain, then prove that $A$ is integrally closed in $A[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Consider the question asked in my commutative algebra assignment:

> If $A$ is an integral domain, then prove that $A$ is integrally closed in $A[x]$. Give an example of $A$ such that $A$ is not integrally closed in $A[x]$.

Attempt: I took the example as $A=\mathbb{Z} $ and gave a counterexample.

But I am not able to prove the assertion. I have to prove that for any polynomial in $A[x]$ with coefficient of highest power $1$ the solution also lies in $A$. But I couldn't think why it should always happen.

I tried also by assuming that there exists $a_0$ ,..., $a_{n-1}$ all in $A$ such that  $x$ in $a_0+a_1 x+... +a_{n-1} x^{n-1} +x^n=0$ doesn't belongs to $A$. But couldn't think of any contradiction.

So, can you please give a hint or two?

Comment: Take $A$ having a nilpotent element

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to do the following:

We want to show that $A$ is integrally closed in $A[X]$, this means that for any polynomial $f\in A[X]$ s.t. there are $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}\in A$ s.t.
$a_0+a_1f+\ldots+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}+f^n=0$ it holds that $f\in A$. So assume $a_0+a_1f+\ldots+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}+f^n=0$ for certain $a_i\in A$. Well, then clearly we must have $$-a_0 = a_1f+\ldots+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}+f^n$$ this implies that $\deg a_0 = \deg (a_1f+\ldots+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}+f^n)$, but since $A$ is integral this can only happen if $\deg f=0$ i.e. $f\in A$ or $f=0$, which also means that $f\in A$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last line "but since A is integral this can only happen if degf=0 i.e. f∈A."?

Comment: If $a_0=0$, then $0=f\cdot (a_1+\cdots+f^{n-1})$. If $A$ is an integral domain, so is $A[X]$, hence we get that $f=0$ and thus, $f\in A$. Suppose $a_0\neq 0$, then $\deg a_0=0$ and $\deg (a_1f+\ldots+f^n)=\deg(f\cdot (a_1+\ldots+f^{n-1})=\deg (f)+\deg(a_1+\ldots+f^{n-1})$. Thus, $\deg(f)=0$ which means $f\in A$. What is crucial is that the formula $\deg (f\cdot g)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$ only holds because $A$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Why can't we have $a_1 +...+f^{n-1} =0$ when $a_0=0$?

Comment: If $n=1$ then $f+a_0=0$ so $f\in A$. So suppose $n>1$ then $n-1>0$. Suppose $\deg f>0$ then $\deg(f^{n-1})=(n-1)\deg(f)>1$ so the term of highest power in $f$ can't canel with anything in the relation $a_1+\ldots+f^{n-1}$.

Comment: " so the term of highest power in f can't cancel with anything in the relation $a_1+…+f^{n−1}$" how does $deg(f^{n-1}) = (n-1) deg(f)$ implies that?

Comment: Can you please reply to my question ?